# No such file or directory with Flask

Tags: python, flask

flask question: I have my `run.py` file in the following dir

```
 /Users/`<username>`/Python_stuff/flask
```

but when I run it it says

```
(api_automation)MacBook-Pro:flask `<username>`$ ./run.py
-bash: ./run.py: flask/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening when its worked in the past on other virtualenv's

here is what the run.py looks like:

```
#!flask/bin/python

from app import app 
app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 20):

Your file starts with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) telling the shell what program to load to run the script. The shebang line is the first line starting with `#!`.

In this case, the shebang tells the shell to run `flask/bin/python`, and that file does not exist in your current location.

The tutorial you got this from expects you to create a virtualenv directory called `flask`, and the script is set up to run the Python binary installed in that directory.

If you are using a different Python location, edit the shebang line to point to the correct location, or use `python run.py` to explicitly name the executable on the command line. In that case the shebang line is ignored.